# Datatables and setinterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have datatables, and i need to automatic refresh maya tables on one half hours, this example code

```
$('#btnmont').on('click', function() {
            var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
            var table = $("#monitor");
            var target = table.attr('data-table');

                var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
                    if (processing) {
                        $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
                    } else{
                        $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
                    };
                } ).DataTable({
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "ajax": host+'monitor/table/'+target,
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": [ -1 ],
                        "className": "dt-body-left",
                    }]
                });

                setInterval (function test() {
                    $("#monitor").DataTable().fnDraw();
                }, 1000);

        });
```

But the set invterval not working, it show warning

> ```
> 264button.js:434 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).fnDraw is not a function
> ```

How do i fixed this???

EDIT : If i change to

```
setInterval (function test() {
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                }, 1000);
```

is still not working

Comment: you have to invoke the function in setInterval ((function test({oTable.fnDraw();})(), 1000);

Comment: maybe you should check it first if it is not undefined if (typeof oTable.fnDraw != 'undefined')

Comment: is still not woring is said not undefined but it said "Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnDraw is not a function"